# Password generator displays kotlin.Unit

Tags: android, string, kotlin, random, passwords

I'm trying to make random password generator based on user input and everything is fine until i use *.toCharArray().shuffle()* function, but without shuffling it's too predictable beacuse it puts letters in pre-determined positions. Is there any way this code would work? Any workaround? I already tried stringbuilder but it bypasses user input so I don't know what to do now.

```
val chars= "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~@#$%^&*()!"

 override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        if (fromUser)
        {
            when(seekBar)
            {
                sbNumberOfLetters ->
                {
                    tvLetterCount.text = progress.toString()
                    smallLetters = progress
                }

                sbNumberOfCapitalLetters ->
                {
                    tvCapitalsCount.text = progress.toString()
                    capitalLetterNumber = progress
                }

                sbNumberOfNumerals ->
                {
                    tvNumeralsCount.text = progress.toString()
                    numeralsNumber = progress
                }

                sbNumberOfSpecialChars ->
                {
                    tvSpecialCharsCount.text = progress.toString()
                    specialCharNumber = progress
                }
            }
        }
    }



 private fun generatePassword() {

        for (y in 1..numeralsNumber)
        {
            var randomLetter = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
            listOfLetters.add(chars[randomLetter].toString())
        }

        for (w in 1..smallLetters)
        {
            var randomLetter = Random.nextInt(10, 36)
            listOfLetters.add(chars[randomLetter].toString())
        }

        for (x in 1..capitalLetterNumber)
        {
            var randomLetter = Random.nextInt(36, 62)
            listOfLetters.add(chars[randomLetter].toString())
        }

        for (z in 1..specialCharNumber)
        {
            var randomLetter = Random.nextInt(63, 73)
            listOfLetters.add(chars[randomLetter].toString())
        }

        password = (listOfLetters.joinToString(separator = "",)).toCharArray().shuffle().toString()

        tvGeneratedPassword.text = password

        listOfLetters.clear()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shuffle` returns `Unit`, so calling `toString()` on `Unit` will return `kotlin.Unit` which is defined in `Unit`. Try this:

```
listOfLetters.shuffle()
val password = listOfLetters.joinToString(separator = "")
tvGeneratedPassword.text = password
```

Comment: On the upside this solution doesn't return kotlin.Unit. Downside is it seems to completely ignore user input. Even with all variables turned to zero it still returns some unwanted 10 letter string. Always begginning with [C@

Comment: @Piotr I thought you want that. Updated answer to shuffle the list and then convert to string. You don't have to call `toCharArray()`

Comment: Okay now I got it just needed to use a few println's to check what is exactly happening. Thank you kindly sir.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well use the tools that Kotlin provides to write expressive and maintainable code ( are the indexes for `Random.nextInt` in the code you provided [correct](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-int.html)? ) . Here is one alternative (here lists and not arrays are used and `shuffled()` returns a new list ) :

```
abstract sealed class RandomChars {
    open val chars: CharArray = charArrayOf()
    fun get(count: Int) = (1..count).map { chars[Random.nextInt(0, chars.size)] }
}
object RandomDigits : RandomChars() {
    override val chars = "0123456789".toCharArray()
}
object RandomLowerCase : RandomChars() {
    override val chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()
}
object RandomUpperCase : RandomChars() {
    override val chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray()
}
object RandomSpecial : RandomChars() {
    override val chars = "~@#$%^&*()!".toCharArray()
}

fun main() {
    val password =
        (RandomDigits.get(1) + RandomLowerCase.get(2) + RandomUpperCase.get(2) + RandomSpecial.get(1))
            .shuffled()
            .joinToString(separator = "")

    println(password) // e.g. %Oa7Mt
}
```

Here is another, more functional approach:

```
val charGenerator =
    { alphabet: CharArray -> { count: Int -> (1..count).map { alphabet[Random.nextInt(0, alphabet.size)] } } }

val randomDigits = charGenerator("0123456789".toCharArray())
val randomLowecase = charGenerator("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray())
val randomUppercase = charGenerator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray())
val randomSpecial = charGenerator("~@#$%^&*()!".toCharArray())

fun main() {
    val password =
        (randomDigits(1) + randomLowecase(2) + randomUppercase(2) + randomSpecial(1))
            .shuffled()
            .joinToString(separator = "")

    println(password) // e.g. %Oa7Mt
}
```